# Configuration of Mosquitto Server to receive message from javascript

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a general question about Mosquitto and MQTT. I managed to setup a Server running Ubuntu and Mosquitto 1.4.2 with websockets ([tutorial here](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2015/05/18/six-steps-to-install-mosquitto-1-4-2-with-websockets-on-debian-wheezy/)). And I want so send some data from a Javascript Application using the mqttws31.js. Both work fine when subscribing to test.mosquitto.org but when I try to to send the "Hello world" to my own server I get a timeout.

What I tried is this:

```
ubuntu@instanz6:~$ mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
1440670543: mosquitto version 1.4.2 (build date 2015-08-27 11:26:53+0200) starting
1440670543: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1440670543: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1440670543: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1440670543: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

and then open the html file shown below. I guess that I'm making a general error / missed a concept but I don't know how to continue ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="js/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var wsbroker = "11.111.11.111";
    var wsport = 1883;
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
        "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
    client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
      console.log("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    };
    client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
      console.log(message.destinationName, ' -- ', message.payloadString);
    };
    var options = {
      timeout: 3,
      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log("mqtt connected");
        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic, you can add multile lines of these
        //client.subscribe('/World', {qos: 1});

        //use the below if you want to publish to a topic on connect
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
        message.destinationName = "/World";
        client.send(message);

      },
      onFailure: function (message) {
        console.log("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
      }
    };
  function init() {
      client.connect(options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 11.111.11.111 - btw isn't the real ip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the port wrong in your JavaScript, it needs to be port 9001 you have configured for Websockets not 1883

```
...
var wsbroker = "11.111.11.111";
var wsport = 1883;
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
    "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
...
```

Should be

```
...
var wsbroker = "11.111.11.111";
var wsport = 9001;
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
    "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
...
```

Comment: thanks for your tip but it still doesn't work ... Connection failed: AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'ws://11.111.11.111:9001/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: OK, so is port 9001 open on the broker machine? no firewall in the way?

Comment: you are my hero!! :) - now it works! thanks a lot!! I'm pretty new to the whole topic so i totally forgot to open the port ... thanks

Comment: another short question - is it possible to display the incoming messages on the cli? when i enter: mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf and then mosquitto_sub -v -t '#' nothing happens when i open the html file besides the message "New client connected from ... "

Comment: had to open a second tab and then enter 'mosquitto_sub -t /#'